# How to run spark-jobs outside the bin folder of spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have an existing `spark-job`, the functionality of this `spark-job` is to connect `kafka-server` get the data and then storing the data into `cassandra tables`, now this `spark-job` is running on server inside `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin` but whenever I am trying to run this `spark-job` from other location, Its not running, this `spark-job` contains some JavaRDD related code.
Is there any chance, I can run this `spark-job` from outside also by adding any dependency in pom or something else?

Comment: How are you running your job? you can run spark-submit from anywhere.

Comment: Yes I am using spark-submit... I am not aware of this that much.. can you pls tell me little bit clearly, actually my seniors are running this, I don't have that much knowledge on this... Can i directly copy spar-submit & my jar into another folder(Ex:- test)  and run there directly ?

Comment: Can you explain _"whenever I am trying to run this spark-job from other location, Its not running"_? What are the errors?

Comment: I think you are specifying relative paths, if you use absolute path it will work from other directories as well.

Comment: Where do you run your spark cluster standalone, yarn, mesos ?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski errors :-
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
        at debug.KafkaToCassandraJob.main(KafkaToCassandraJob.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) '

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I am trying to run this `spark-job` from other location, Its not running

`spark-job` is a custom launcher script for a Spark application, perhaps with some additional command-line options and packages. Open it, review the content and fix the issue.

If it's too hard to figure out what `spark-job` does and there's no one nearby to help you out, it's likely time to throw it away and replace with the good ol' `spark-submit`.

*Why don't you use it in the first place?!*

Read up on `spark-submit` in [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).